# How to use MATLAB sessions to run multiple While loops together

Tags: matlab, session, while-loop

I have Multiple while loops, each while loop is assiociated with a push button, how can i use sessions in matlab to run each while loop independentely on different cores ?

Comment: Why do you need to do it? It'd be much much easier to just put all code into one loop.

Comment: Putting it in one loop requires me to handle to much if conditions, especially that while loops are used for streaming and the frame rate will be divided

Comment: Please share the code you have already, it will make it easier to help.